# SQL for "Give me all of the strings in this set literal that aren't in this query result" (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an arbitrarily long set of email addresses.

I want to know which of these addresses are NOT in: `SELECT email FROM user_table;`

I have tried various forms of:

```
SELECT 
('test@example.com', 'test1@example.com','test2@example.com','test3@example.com','test4@example.com','test5@example.com')
EXCEPT
(select email from user_table);
```

I cannot get past the error: `ERROR: EXCEPT types record and character varying cannot be matched`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT v.email
FROM (VALUES ('test@example.com'),
             ('test1@example.com'), 
             ('test2@example.com'), 
             ('test3@example.com'), 
             ('test4@example.com'), 
             ('test5@example.com')
     ) v(email)
EXCEPT
SELECT email 
FROM user_table;
```

Comment: I got: `SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
  Position: 242` until I changed it to what's in my answer below.  I couldn't format the code well in this comment, but if you edit yours so it doesn't throw errors in Postgres I will accept it.  Thank you!

Comment: @AlexTotheroh . . . I fixed the typo.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change @gordon-linoff 's code slightly to work with Postgres:

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES ('test0@example.com'),
             ('test1@example.com'), 
             ('test2@example.com')
     ) AS foo
EXCEPT
(SELECT email 
FROM user_table);
```